# content security policy: allow site A to embed content from site B (csp blocked error appears on site A)

Tags: apache, content-security-policy

One of our servers (**VideoServer**) recently had its config changed.  Since that time I'm getting Content Security Policy errors with pages served from **FrontEndServer**, where those pages have an embedded iframe sourced to **VideoServer**

I've gone so far as to temporarily set FrontEndServer's httpd config to have only the following header:  `Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW`, being sure to restart the httpd service after the change.

Continue to get CSP error when viewing the front end content on `FrontEndServer`:

```
Blocked by Content Security Policy

An error occurred during a connection to VideoServer.
```

Is it possible to configure `VideoServer's` CSP policy such that `FrontEndServer` would get CSP blocked errors when attempting to iframe content from `VideoServer`?  I'm not wanting that to happen, am trying to track down what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Got this sorted by more closely reading documentation.   I needed to configure `VideoServer` to allow specific external sites (eg, `FrontEndServer`) to display it's content.  This is handled with the `frame-ancestors` option.

`FrontEndServer` config:
(note we are aware about the inline styles/scripts - this is a legacy site so a lot of work has to be done)

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' ursula.genetics.emory.edu https://www.googletagmanager.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://browser-update.org ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://googletagmanager.com https://browser-update.org https://www.googletagmanager.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src 'self' VideoServerURL; "
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Header set X-WebKit?-CSP: "default-src 'self'"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "master-only"
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
```

`VideoServer` config:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' FrontEndServerURL;"
Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Header set X-WebKit-CSP: "default-src 'self'"
Header set X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: "master-only"
Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires 0
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains
```

Hope someone else finds this of use.